# What is the easiest way to keep track of a group of checkable buttons in QT?

Tags: button, qt4, groupbox

I have six checkable push buttons in QT, and I want it so that only one of the buttons are checked at one time (like radio buttons). I could probably do it with lots of signals and slots, but is there a easier way to do this?

I'm looking for something similar to how the QGroupBox and QRadioButtons work together.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qbuttongroup.html .

Make sure all of your buttons are checkable, make the group exclusive, use addButton() for each button and run with it.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking at the 4.6 docs, and they weren't very clear... This is what I wanted.